# How to make object isKinematic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have game character that is walking on a platform. There are also blocks falling from the sky. when the character is on the ground and a block hits it on top of the head i want to make the blocks Kinematic. I have problems with the last set of code
`rigidbody2D.isKinematic("Block",true);`  the code is on my character and i want it so if it hit it the block freezes

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Stop : MonoBehaviour {
    bool grounded = false;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    float groundRadius = .5f;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    void FixedUpdate () 
     {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
     }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
     {
        if (grounded && col.gameObject.tag == "Block") 
        {   

            rigidbody2D.isKinematic("Block",true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you are referencing the rigid body that is attached to the game object that your script is attached to... replace "rigidbody2D.isKinematic("Block",true); with "col.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true;"

Comment: It is not working I am getting this error. "Assets/Prefab/Stop.cs(19,29): error CS1061: Type UnityEngine.Collision2D' does not contain a definition for rigidbody2D' and no extension method rigidbody2D' of type UnityEngine.Collision2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that "col" is already defining that it is a 2D object. So you have to take away the 2D from the ridgidbody. This should work.

```
col.rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

isKinematic is a bool property, not a function. set it as follows:

```
 col.rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
```

UPDATE: [Collision2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html) uses [rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-rigidbody.html). [Collider2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html) (for triggers) uses [rigidbody2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-rigidbody2D.html) or [attachedRigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D-attachedRigidbody.html). Either can use col.[gameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D-gameObject.html).rigidBody2D.

Comment: It is not working I am getting this error.  "Assets/Prefab/Stop.cs(19,29): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Collision2D' does not contain a definition for `rigidbody2D' and no extension method `rigidbody2D' of type `UnityEngine.Collision2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Sorry. I don't have Unity handy so running off memory & the docs. Try col.attachedRigidbody2D.isKinematic or col.gameObject.rigidbody2D.isKinematic

Comment: Mixed up collisions & triggers. Updated now.